# subtract values in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, subtraction

I want to subtract values of two sums of two columns on the same table. Ej:

```
select DOMAINID, sum(MAXIMO), sum(MINIMO)
from TU_MEMORIA_SERVIDOR_HIS;

APLICACION|SUM(MAX) |SUM (MIN)
APLICACION|177862176|175412792
```

So that the output looks like this:

```
APLICACION|SUM(MAX) |SUM(MAX)-SUM(MIN)
APLICACION|177862176|2449384
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You would do just what you wrote: `SUM(maximo) - SUM(minimo)`.

```
SELECT SUM(maximo), SUM(maximo) - SUM(minimo)
FROM tu_memoria_servidor_his;
```

[Here it is in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65728/2/0).